# Typo3 (7.6.4) Extbase New Action arguments empty after submit

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-flow

if I submit my New Action and the form is not valid, then I can't get the submited post vars. $this->request->getArguments() is empty at my new action.

```
/**
 * action new
 *
 * @param \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Protokoll $newProtokoll
 * @return void
 */
public function newAction(\Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Protokoll $newProtokoll = null)
{

    $this->view->assign('newProtokoll', $newProtokoll);
    .....
    $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arguments);
    echo "</pre>";
    ....
```

->empty

Comment: Found a solution at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936733/parameters-to-action-lost-when-validation-error-occurs

Answer (score 2):

You should have the `newAction` for showing the form and a separate `createAction` for validating the data and entering in the database. If the form is not valid, the user is returned to the newAction with the $newProtokoll object containing the entered data.

YOU SHOULD NOT use `$this->request->getArguments()` as this is automatically casted if you have it in your method arguments.

In the blog example this is explained very detailed:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/3-BlogExample/11-Alternative-route-creating-a-new-posting.html